# http.delete in Angular 2 not working

Tags: json, angular, ionic2, angular-http

Good day guys, I am currently having difficulty with the `http.delete` in Angular2. I am trying to delete a record in my JSON API but there is nothing that was being deleted. Here is my code:

```
 let headers= new Headers();
                   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');   

                   let options= new RequestOptions({headers:headers});
                   this.http.delete('http://sample.xyz/xxx/api.php/cart?filter=cart.customer_id,eq,21&transform=1',options)
                   .subscribe((ok)=>{
                     console.log("Successfully Deleted." +ok)
                   }, (err) => {
                     this.showPopup("Oops!", "Something went wrong on deletion." +err);
                   });
```

And here is the record I want to delete('`http://sample.xyz/xxx/api.php/cart?filter=cart.customer_id,eq,21&transform=1`'):

```
cart: [
{
cart_id: 25,
customer_id: 21,
prod_id: 27,
cart_quantity: 2,
cart_subtotal: "2710",
cart_datetime_added: "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
cart_type: "Mobile"
},
{
cart_id: 26,
customer_id: 21,
prod_id: 27,
cart_quantity: 10,
cart_subtotal: "2710",
cart_datetime_added: "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
cart_type: "Mobile"
},
{
cart_id: 27,
customer_id: 21,
prod_id: 128,
cart_quantity: 2,
cart_subtotal: "800",
cart_datetime_added: "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
cart_type: "Mobile"
},
{
cart_id: 36,
customer_id: 21,
prod_id: 10,
cart_quantity: 5,
cart_subtotal: "895",
cart_datetime_added: "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
cart_type: "Mobile"
},
{
cart_id: 42,
customer_id: 21,
prod_id: 104,
cart_quantity: 2,
cart_subtotal: "4500",
cart_datetime_added: "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
cart_type: "Mobile"
}
]
```

Any suggestions guys on how can I delete this records? Hope you guys can help me. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What error in console ?

Comment: there is no error. It's just that the data is not being deleted. Is my code for delete correct?

Comment: When you create the request is the response 200?

Comment: Yes @BogdanBogdanov. Here is the response: Successfully Deleted.Response with status: 200 OK for URL: http://sample.xyz/xxx/api.php/cart?filter=cart.customer_id,eq,21&transform=1

Comment: Could you please share the PHP code which handles the request?

Comment: Sorry sir but I do not use PHP, I am using Angular2. The code is what I shown in the question above.